# /usr/bin/git: /usr/bin/git: cannot execute binary file from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am executing a shell script from Jenkins and both Jenkins and the directory of GIT exists on the same machine but end up in getting the following error:-

/usr/bin/git: /usr/bin/git: cannot execute binary file

Jenkins Console Log

Git Pull Started :-

/usr/bin/git: /usr/bin/git: cannot execute binary file

Linux Terminal :-

azureuser@MagentoStage03:~/magento-deployment$ which git

/usr/bin/git

Yes it’s a freestyle project and executing Execute Shell option. Please help

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/435988/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-cannot-execute-binary-file is probably relevant

Comment: @AlanBirtles I can run commands from terminal. But I am trying to execute a shell script from Jenkins and I am getting this error.

Comment: Please use the `Git Plugin`. Did the `git clone` succeed?

Comment: I am executing a shell script from Jenkins and here is the content of the shell script:-

    
{export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/git; <br>

echo "Deployment Started - Magento Staging"; <br>

sudo su - magento;

cd /usr01/www/albi_magento/;

echo "Git Pull Started";
sudo su - magento git pull
echo "Git pull done"
sudo  rm -rf --  generated/code/* var/cache/*
echo "Applying Permission"
sudo  chmod -R -- 777 var/ generated/
echo "Permission granted with read and write"
php bin/magento cache:flush
echo "Cache flush done"}

Comment: Please add the above information to your question , it is not very clear what you are trying to do. Is it a `Freestyle` job? Are you using the `Execute Shell` option to execute it?

Comment: Yes it’s a freestyle project and executing it Execute Shell option. Please help

Comment: Have you set the GIT path on global tool configuration page ??

Comment: Yes already added but it says no such path exist with GIt.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely due to the use of `su`.
I solved a similar issue by using:

```
sudo -u <username> <command>
```

instead of

```
su - <username> <command>
```

Not sure how you can apply this to Jenkins, though.